# Why is the 部首 of 詈 "言" instead of "四"？

Tags: radicals

Both "言" and "四" are radicals (部首). For "[詈](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?ccd=why35m&o=e0&sec1=1&op=sid=%22W00000003487%22.&v=-2)", the radical is 言, not 四. Why? In general, when there is more than one part which can be a radical, which one will be the radical for the character?

Answer (score 1):

部首 is typically (but not in all cases) used to illustrate a character's fundamental feature. 
`詈` means to curse, so it is related with `言`(speak, remark, words etc.).

Comment: Thanks! It makes perfect sense. When I look the character up in a dictionary, I need to know the radical before knowing the meaning of the character.

Comment: @Zuriel I would strongly recommend using handwriting recognition tools attached to a digital dictionary, like Pleco, and not paper dictionaries which rely on the radical system.

Comment: Cool! Please select my reply as the answer :)

Comment: Just as 咒, (Zhòu), (religious incantations / "curse"), where both 口 & 几 are radicals, has the "mouth" radical, in fact two "mouths", in case one gets tired I suppose or perhaps two mouths are louder than one? :) "几", ( jǐ ), looks like and stands for a small table.